# Bea Weblogic - Oracle JDBC Connection failed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, datasource

I am creating a simple JDBC connection data source from Bea Weblogic console, using my mac OS X Macbook (Yosemite). Something does not work.

I'm using the following parameters:

```
Driver Name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@anagrafe:1521:MY_SERVICE_NAME
```

**USERNAME** and **PASSWORD** Are right.

Trying to connect from the **jDeveloper IDE**, using the same parameters, **everything is ok**, but doing the connection from Bea WebLogic Server Administration Console 12c, running locally, I register the following connection:

```
<15-gen-2015 11.33.37 CET> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Errore di I/O: Invalid argument
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:816)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:614)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:340)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:22)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:254)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:251)
    at com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:751)
    at com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:479)
[...........]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at oracle.net.nt.MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:759)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:312)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:168)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1606)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:539)
```

Looks like it cannot logon... Any Idea?

Tanks a lot, Davide.

Comment: On the jdbc connection pool tab, you have a user set in the properties like `user=my_user`? It sounds like you have a property wrong or your connection URL is bad, even though it looks ok here. Also, are you sure you're using the correct driver jar file? The name looks ok

Comment: Comparing with a windows or linux installation everything looks right, as ever... This looks like a proxy error... I did a workaround, I linked to a remote installation... Than I changed job this Friday :D, so I have no other possibilities to check this trouble again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Best of luck at the new job!